# Typescript method decorator to ensure a specific method return type

Tags: typescript

I have made a few decorators to make routing easy with `express` (e.i. `@Get()`, `@Post`) which are used to map class functions to a route.

I would like the targeted method's return type to systematically be of type `HttpResponse` and have ts or the IDE throw an error when another type is returned:

```
export type HttpResponse = { data?: any; status?: number; } | object;
```

For instance:

```
@Post()
login(email: string, password: string) : object {   // <-- highlights method as returning the wrong type
   return {};
}

@Post()
async register(email: string, password: string) : Promise<HttpResponse> {   // <-- all good
   return {};
}
```

Can this be achieved? Could this be done using a custom `tsconfig` rule?

PS: Decorators are very knew to me and I might be extrapolating how decorators can be used.

Comment: Off-topic, but before you implement your own decorator library, you might want to look into NestJS or other existing server frameworks.

Comment: I've looked into that but wanted to have a go with decorators myself to understand them better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume your `Post` decorator looks like this

```
declare function Post(): MethodDecorator
```

If you look what `MethodDecorator` type in TS definitions looks like, you'll find

```
declare type MethodDecorator = <T>(
    target: Object,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>,
) => TypedPropertyDescriptor<T> | void
```

It's not clear to me, why this type is not generic (the function it declares it generic, but the type itself is not), TS developpers must've had their reasons for this. Anyway, since you worked with decorators, you know, that this third argument is the descriptor of the property you attach your decorator to, here it's of type `WhateverTypeIsUsedToTypeDescriptors<T>`. You can declare your own decorator type that only expects this property to be a function that returns `HttpResponse` by replacing this `T` with your type:

```
type HttpMethod = (...args: any[]) => HttpResponse
type HttpMethodDecorator = (
    target: Object,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<HttpMethod>,
) => TypedPropertyDescriptor<HttpMethod> | void

declare function Post(): HttpMethodDecorator
```

See how this works in [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcASMZgErAM6QB2eqAvHAN5wAmAhjLQPwBccthiA3HHgzAK54WcQvwC2AI2BRuAXzgAfOBAkArYAGMYAWABQepCnSYwAWWAwAFhGpxyACgB0z2lADmeVu0QBtALoAlHYAfMZYuAQQxMB61JoANq6ohqgYWOZWNgAimtD00HZw9npwpQiubhasAPJqmjAANCVlYFAQKLCIANLAiKy8UACWhG6KPIiSEPFNumU0+BpDYDDQrAAqyMDUAAptHUg5eIuDy9AAPGlmFtbUwTNBpKEbKDt70gcLSytQFyYZN6ElAA3CCDah6WIJJJwABm-EIWkGUTg2wgvHsAVYl3+2VyUHyUAhug0iTweDgpkQaHY1Hi0kozVKAAFUeiggB6dlwACiUDahNmZXiEDcw3swDEtEG8X6MCGIwacDAtDJAHdoNRZfK3JieHLhqMKIy5nAoBZ+FBCHAAEQASQA5GIRBB4LQ4EDaPEwab8EQSNbOMbZES5iy0TAMXBOXAAGLDGKC0pm0W8aTiyXSrUGxXKtUarMjXWXCJ+1BGxMms0CS2UYMVuuyIA): if I try to decorate a method that returns `string` instead of `HttpResponse`, it shows an error (for some reason it says that `HttpMethod` is not assignable to `(email: string, password: string) => string` although you probably would expect it to be vice versa, but whatever).

That's the main idea, now to clean up a little bit you may want to make this type generic:

```
type MethodDecorator<T extends Function> = (
    target: Object,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>,
) => TypedPropertyDescriptor<T> | void

declare function Post(): MethodDecorator<(...args: any[]) => HttpResponse>
```

Also don't forget to let it accept promises

```
declare function Post(): MethodDecorator<(...args: any[]) => HttpResponse | Promise<HttpResponse>>
```

Heck, you could even type the function's arguments or basically anything, enjoy :P

Also I'm not sure why you want TS to highlight `login` as returning the wrong type, because it returns `object` and in `HttpResponse` you have `whatever | object` so it shouldn't really be an error